# Need loop for job placement selection that changes

Tags: excel, vba

So folks i am just starting out learning how to use vba and macros.  what i am trying to figure out is how to be able to run this macro and select all the cells in a specific column, to also have it skip the grey x's and remove all duplicates.  any help would be appreciated.

```vb
Sub placements()
    Dim SrcRange As Range, FillRange As Range
    Dim c As Range, r As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim BlankCells As Range
    
    
    Set SrcRange = Worksheets("Placements").Range("A2:A8")
    Set FillRange = Selection
    Set BlankCells = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
      
      If TypeName(Selection) <> "Range" Then Exit Sub
      Application.ScreenUpdating = False
      On Error Resume Next
     
    
    r = SrcRange.Cells.Count
    For Each c In FillRange
    Do
    c.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(SrcRange, Int((r * Rnd) + 1))
    Loop Until WorksheetFunction.Count(FillRange, c.Value, BlankCells) < 2
    
    Next
    
End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please describe in more detail what "place people in the job assignments that they have" means, and let us know what the specific problem is with your existing code: what does it do or not do which is different from what you want?

Comment: So i work for a janitorial cleaning company and what i am trying to do is to try and get it to where i have to hit a button and everyone is assigned there cleaning jobs for the day.  the main issue that i am having is that i can get it to put people in there job assignments but i have to select around the x's to get it to work.  It just has duplicates because i have to select around the x's.  I did also add a pic of the jobs that they have to do.  I also have added a pic of the results that i am getting as well.  Would also like to be able to select whole column and try and skip x's

Comment: What's in A2:A8?  What should the final result look like?  What does the yellow shaded area in your screenshot represent?  Are you saying that you need to be able to select a range and then populate the empty cells in the selection with a value chosen randomly from the list you uploaded?

Comment: A2:A8 is the range for the job placement that are on a separate sheet that is listed in the coding. The yellow area is for a person that has a different schedule. Then the other people.  Yes I would like to be able to do that and also have no duplicate cells as well.

Comment: Let me ask the question this way is there any way that i can do an if statement to where it skips the cells with the value X in it.  Those are the days that the people would have off.

Comment: `If Len(c.Value)=0 Then` - process the cell

Comment: Tried processing just one cell with an X in it and it didnt work.  tried with multiple cells that were blank and had the X in them and it filled all the cells also was saying i needed an End If.

Comment: I can't answer here, so maybe you can post a new question and I will post an answer there

Comment: did a new post.